# How to hide bin and obj folder from being displayed in solution explorer

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

I have a windows forms application in VB. My project is working fine, but I would like to hide the bin and obj from being displayed in solution explorer.

The reason being that I could see other forms application in project in similar( bin and obj not displayed in solution explorer) way all though they have the bin and obj as folders.

Comment: unclick `Show All Files` at the top of Solution Explorer

Comment: Plutonix is right, if they appear "fuzzy" or gray, then you have the solution explorer set to show everything. If you are actually included in your project though, right click the folders (bin and obj, respectively) in the solution explorer, then click "Exclude from Project".

Comment: I wish I could accept Plutonix's answer. Thanks for saving my day.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

One of the buttons at the top of Solution Explorer is to **Hide/Show All Files**. When on/pressed/Show, the `bin` and `obj` folders show as dotted lines (may depend on themes and settings) to show they are VS folders:

[image]

Note that when you have it as `Hide` some other things are hidden. **My Project** for instance can no longer be opened/expanded:

[image]

The **My Project** files are all VS/Designer files which can be changed elsewhere (Settings tab for instance), but sometimes it is nice to just open one to check something.

Unlike C# projects, VB also hides **References** so you cant right click it for the short Reference context menu.  `Add Reference` is still on the longer **Project** context menu and of course in **Project Properties**.