# Form splits into 3 items

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

[image]

As you can see, one form is split into 3 items: .Designer.vb, .resx and .vb.

The .Designer.vb and .resx should be children of the .vb file.

The other forms in the project are okay, they have a valid hierarchy.

Does anybody know why this might happen and how to avoid it?

Comment: One is the code you typically use, one is the code NET needs to create the form and one is the resources you used in the form.  Why would you want to avoid it?

Comment: Examine your .vbproj file for missing attributes SubType and DependentUpon.

Comment: If you turn off [show all files in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26141001/1070452) those wont show...if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @Plutonix Those first two files should be child nodes of the last file.  I *think* that's the issue here.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes, that is what I'm confused about.

Comment: I took a look at the vbprj file: When it goes wrong, it looks like this:     <Compile Include="frmAudioRecorderInput.Designer.vb" />
    <Compile Include="frmAudioRecorderInput.vb">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile> When it goes right, it looks like this:     <Compile Include="frm1a.Designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>frm1a.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>

Comment: I guess I have to fix that mess up with a small project that corrects this. Why oh why is there no way to fix it automatically in VS2015? :-(

Comment: Remove the files from the project (right-click each one and Exclude from project), then add the form file back (Add ... existing file)

Comment: @HardCode Then this form's controls disappear. :-( I guess the .Designer file is not found anymore when I click "Add to solution again". Also, I have like 80 forms, so I prefer fixing this with a small program.

Comment: Adding the form back doesn't restore all three files with the relationships? I swear I fixed this same problem once doing it this way.

Comment: @HardCode For me it doesn't, but thank you so much anyway!

Comment: Did you try selecting all the three files and adding them at the very same time? -- I don't use VS 2015 but if I get the time tomorrow I could examine one of my `.vbproj`-files and perhaps be able to point out things that could possibly be wrong inside yours.

Comment: Answering your vbproj comment: Can't you just simply put `<DependentUpon>frmAudioRecorderInput.vb</DependentUpon>` inside the `<Compile>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a normal `.vbproj`-file of Visual Studio 2010 a form's files are declared like so:

```xml
<Compile Include="Form1.vb">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Form1.Designer.vb">
  <DependentUpon>Form1.vb</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
```

This is located inside a `<ItemGroup>` tag, then the `.resx`-file is located under the next `<ItemGroup>` tag (but putting them in the same should not be a problem as far as I know):

```xml
<EmbeddedResource Include="Form1.resx">
  <DependentUpon>Form1.vb</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

So here we see that it's the `<DependentUpon>` tag that indicates the relationship between files, i.e. every child file includes it.

There's no automatic fix for this other than excluding and re-importing all files at the same time, I think. But since that apparently did not work for you, you'd just have to edit the `.vbproj`-file manually and follow this structure for every broken form.